# Does MageReport offer any static ip or a range of ips I can whitelist for our dev site?

Tags: magereport

I'd like to run these scans on our test/dev sites, but they're currently behind a IP restricted firewall.

Are you able to provide your public IPs so that I can whitelist them for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can whitelist the Magereport IP's by whitelisting the following IPs:

```
188.166.64.179
178.62.230.112
```

Note that these IPs are subject to change, so you might want to keep an eye on https://www.magereport.com/static/ips.txt which is where we'll be listing all the IPs Magereport is currently using.

Disclaimer: I work on Magereport :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried whitelisting 188.166.64.179?

Www a record

https://intodns.com/magereport.com